# Why don't negative margins work in IE 7?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-7

I declared a negative margin on a link, but it doesn't work on IE 7.

```
#search a {
    color: #E5E5E5;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    float:right;
    margin-top:-20px; // this is not working on ie, only mozilla
}
```

Is there a fix for this?

Comment: `<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">`

Comment: probably doctype incompatibility coupled with a not being display: block(IE doesn't give layout to an element not explicitly having display: block even if you float it)

Comment: i tried display block, it deosnt work yet :((

Comment: can you make a jsfiddle of your problem?

Comment: yeh i will give me a minute thanks?

Comment: i thought you added display: block in it? http://jsfiddle.net/ZFJyy/4/

Comment: i did but i removed it!!! :) sorry

Answer (score 8):

`{position: relative;}` may be  required, as already noted, but you may have another problem:

In general, IE7 will not draw the part of an element that protrudes outside of its parent container if negative margins is the technique used to pull the element out that way (though it will respect other means of effecting protrusion, like `{overflow: visible}`).

This is a "hasLayout" -related, IE bug <strike>, and a thorough treatment of it can be found at "[Has Layout: Negative Margin Bug](http://haslayout.net/css/Negative-Margin-Bug)</strike>.

As the above-cited reference notes, there are ways of coaxing IE7 to paint the part of an element with negative margins that protrudes outside its parent, but it involves "... to not use any properties that give an element layout."  and that is potentially  restrictive to other design techniques you'd like to use, and has other side effects (again, see cited reference).

But to answer your question: for the workaround, see [the list of properties that induce "hasLayout"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/platform-apis/aa752723(v%3Dvs.85)), (like position, height and width -- yikes!) and be sure none of them are applied to your container.

Comment: Thank you very much, {position: relative;} fixed my problem. I was going crazy with that IE7 bug!

Comment: for the record: I found salvation in ´position: relative;´ plus ´zoom: 1;´. — ( I had given my main "classic" single-column layout a negative right margin, with inner float elements for two/three-column layouts... which broke to early )

Answer (score 1):

Set position: relative; 
This is a good guide for using negative margins http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/07/27/the-definitive-guide-to-using-negative-margins/

Comment: It actually works for me check http://omar.happypunkpanda.com/stack/negative-left.html, i added borders to the body container so you can see the -30px left

Comment: oh wow, u even fixed the text input problem, is it okay if you can show what you chnaged exactly thank you, im a bit too slow!!

Comment: Well I didn't change anything, you can check the code, i basically added a container, verify you are resetting elements, or maybe the style it's being override, if you put your whole code, i might be able to help you out. GL

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you set a valid Doctype. Quirks mode doesn't allow negative margins.